# Regression for each Customer and Product combination using R

Tags: r

I am relatively new to the field of Data Science & R programming. There is requirement where we need to perform linear regression on the combination of Customer & Product. The Response variable here is the ORDERED_QTY and the Dependent variables are STOCK_IN_HAND, PREVIOUS_QTY. 
The sample data would look somewhat like this.

```
Customer Product STOCK_IN_HAND  PREVIOUS_QTY   ORDERED_QTY

C1         P1      10             20              30

C1         P1      5              30              20 

C1         P1      15             20              25 

C1         P2      5              10              20 

C1         P2      5              20              25 

C1         P2      10             25              30 

C2         P1      20             20              30 

C2         P1      10             30              35 
. . . .
```

As per the above data set, we have to create regression model for different customer & product combination (like C1 + P1). Usually we create the model using lm() on the training data set and predict the outcome using predict() using the test data set. 
In this case we have to predict the ORDERED_QTY, when Customer, Product, STOCK_IN_HAND & PREVIOUS_QTY are passed as input.
This is the first time we have come across this type of requirement and not getting a lead on how to proceed. Any input or suggestion will be of immense help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using `tidyverse` package:

First you need to prepare one dataset with training and test data labeled by column (`train_test` in my example):

```
data <-
  tibble(
    Customer = sample(str_c('C', 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    Product = sample(str_c('P', 1:5), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    STOCK_IN_HAND = rpois(1000, 10),
    PREVIOUS_QTY = rpois(1000, 20),
    ORDERED_QTY = rpois(1000, 25),
    train_test = sample(c('train', 'test'), 1000, replace = TRUE)
  )
```

Then you can fit the linear models to each Customer-Product combination separately and make predictions on corresponding data like this:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Customer, Product) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    train = map(data, ~filter(.x, train_test == 'train')),
    test = map(data, ~filter(.x, train_test == 'test') %>% select(-ORDERED_QTY)),
    model = map(train, ~lm(ORDERED_QTY ~ STOCK_IN_HAND + PREVIOUS_QTY, data = .x)),
    pred = map2(model, test, ~predict(.x, newdata = .y))
  ) %>%
  select(Customer, Product, test, pred) %>%
  unnest()
```

Please click through my example and let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your solution. One query though. After the model is built and the command is executed, it is throwing warning messages like ...                                                                   Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  problem with term 2 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned.                        
Could you please help me understand, what is causing these warnings to appear. Many thanks, Amit

Comment: I made simple mistake in the formula. It was:
ORDERED_QTY ~ STOCK_IN_HAND + ORDERED_QTY
while it supposed to be:
ORDERED_QTY ~ STOCK_IN_HAND + PREVIOUS_QTY